# JavaFx conversion and printing

Tags: java, javafx, text, printing

Ok. I am attempting to make a simple little text editor for java practice. I have a TextArea in JavaFX 8 that I type text into. I would like to be able to create and fill a Text object and then send that text object to the printer. So far, I have failed miserably. The printer just spits out a blank sheet of paper.  It's acting as if there is no content to be printed.

I found an example where the text object is wrapped in java's TextFlow like this..

```
TextFlow printArea = new TextFlow(new Text(textDocument.getText()));
```

that at least prints SOMETHING, but it's only the first line of text entered.

Here is my print code:

```
static void printOperation(TextArea textDocument) {

    Text extractedText = new Text(textDocument.getText());
    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if (printerJob != null && printerJob.showPageSetupDialog(textDocument.getScene().getWindow())
            && printerJob.showPrintDialog(textDocument.getScene().getWindow())) {

        if (printerJob.printPage(extractedText)) {
            printerJob.endJob();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to print");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Canceled");
    }
}

//There is a print menu option that calls the print method
        print.setOnAction((ActionEvent e) -> {
            printOperation(textDocument);
        });
```

Comment: `job.printPage(textDocument);`

Comment: Thanks, but I don't want to print that node. I'm following instructions to fill a text object with the node's contents and then print that. Text extractedText = new Text(textDocument.getText()); That doesn't work for some reason. I have to some how make that Text object printable.

Comment: Does `job.printPage(textDocument);` work ?

Comment: Hello.. It prints the entire node. It's just a blank TextArea with a few words in it, but it prints out as a blueish square with the text in it. Almost like I took a picture of my computer screen with my camera or something.

Answer (score 0):

`Text` by seems to have it's origin at the bottom left corner of the node not at the top left one. The text simply is not inside the printed area.

The second attempt probably fails to achieve the desired output, since you do not set any limit for the width.

You could ensure the node is on screen by using a `StackPane` as parent of the text. Furthermore I recommend setting the `wrappingWidth` property:

```
static void printOperation(TextArea textDocument) {
    Text extractedText = new Text(textDocument.getText());
    extractedText.setWrappingWidth(450);

    // use pane to place the text
    StackPane container = new StackPane(extractedText);
    container.setAlignment(Pos.TOP_LEFT);

    PrinterJob printerJob = PrinterJob.createPrinterJob();

    if (printerJob != null && printerJob.showPageSetupDialog(textDocument.getScene().getWindow())
            && printerJob.showPrintDialog(textDocument.getScene().getWindow())) {

        if (printerJob.printPage(container)) {
            printerJob.endJob();
        } else {
            System.out.println("Failed to print");
        }
    } else {
        System.out.println("Canceled");
    }
}
```

You should probably set the `wrappingWidth` according to the page size/margin chosen by the user instead of hardcoding the value though...